# Install Fast-CGI in Apache Server2

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

I am trying to install `fastcgi` in Apache2:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Results in a:

```
 Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate.
```

It seems that also fastcgi.com is not working anymore for getting information.  Is there any way I can install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `libapache2-mod-fcgid` not `libapache2-mod-fastcgi`.

According to the description for `libapache2-mod-fcgid` I think it's what you're looking for?

`libapache2-mod-fcgid - FastCGI interface module for Apache 2`